# how to change or convert genereated JSON structure

Tags: java, json, kendo-treeview

I have generated this json

```
[["22","Tehran","12"],["33","Qazvin","14"]]
```

but this doesn't do what I want
and I want to convert it to something like this so I can access field names to use it in my kendo tree

```
[{"ID":"22","TITLE":"Tehran","ID_COURTZONE":"12"},{"ID":"33","TITLE":"Qazvin","ID_COURTZONE":"14"}]
```

Comment: How are you generating the JSON?

Comment: If you want to change the JSON, you have to change the code that *generates* it. Alternately you can change the structure of the array once you parsed the JSON, by simply iterating over it.

Comment: @Barmar this is the way I generate it:
lst =  ObjectQuery.SelectEntities("Select A.ID, A.TITLE, A.PARENT_COURTBRANCH From COURTBRANCH as A");

return lst;

Comment: @FelixKling can you tell me how to do that?